# How to extract the drive letter and treat it as a variable, or alternatively specify a relative path?

Tags: files-and-directories, installation

Say that on my hard drive I have got the Mathematica program and also a directory that contains a subdirectory of text and data files and another subdirectory of Mathematica notebooks. I use the notebooks to process the text and data files.

Then say I duplicate all of the above on a flash drive, which I use when working on other computers, including in public libraries. I do the syncing by hand.

In the notebooks, I specify the paths of the text and data files by beginning with the drive letter. On my home system, my hard drive is C. On a library system, my flash drive might be called anything, perhaps H. Problem: how to avoid having different copies of the notebooks for the hard drive and the flash drive, with paths specified as beginning C on one and H on the other.

**Is there a way when running *Mathematica* to extract the letter that the OS assigns to the drive that *Mathematica* itself is installed on?**

**Alternatively, can I specify file paths relatively and if so, how?**

I'd be interested in both ways of doing it.

Comment: Do you know about `$InstallationDirectory` and `NotebookDirectory[]`?

Comment: No I didn't. Thanks for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the name of the drive where Mathematica is installed (In windows) using [`FileNameTake`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FileNameTake.html)and [`$InstallationDirectory`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/$InstallationDirectory.html)

```
FileNameTake[$InstallationDirectory, 1]
(* "C:\\" *)
```

The advice by Thies Heidecke is also a good idea, just keep all the references relatives to the [`NotebookDirectory`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NotebookDirectory.html).

```
FileNameJoin[{NotebookDirectory[], "File.name"}]
```

---

<sub>Code tested in *Mathemathica 11.1.1* on Win7</sub>

Comment: Excellent. Many thanks! I've now also found `StringTake[Directory[],1]`, which is uglier and grabs just the "C" (I'm unlikely to be on a system with more than 26 drives), but the relative path method seems more straightforward. It is so impressive that Mathematica makes these things so easy.